# ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError when using Tab inside a Form

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I have tabs inside a form including input fields from the outer form.
On rendering the side I get the following error:

```
ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'false'. Current value: 'true'.
```

According to the stack trace in Chrome the following line is faulty:

[image]

I guess the error has something to do with the angular change detection mechanism and the component tree. If the input fields of the form are put before the tabs and the tabs don't contain form elements belonging to the outer form there is no ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError. Maybe the detected changed value is the validity of the form.

Reproduction scenario with plunker: https://embed.plnkr.co/lZgCb0cyX8TnZ2j8ZE4O

See comments for reproducing the error.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please do not use images to show code as it is bad SO etiquette. Instead add the code directly in a formatted code block. I think every OS provides copy and paste functionality these days so it should be easier than making a screenshot...

Comment: are you using the default ChangeDetectionStrategy in this component?   (you are unless you have specifically changed it to OnPush)

Comment: Its hard to know without seeing the rest of the code, but I'm assuming the ng-template element is defined there in the picture, and then embedded into a viewcontainer elsewhere. Ng-template elements aren't rendered, they just store references to chunks of template code, sort of removing them from the normal change detection trickle down path. Using them in a nested fashion like it seems you have is definitely going to put things out of sync, especially if they reference variables from adjacent elements which will no longer be adjacent after embedding elsewhere.

Comment: ng-template elements are best used to define little isolated (or as isolated as possible) chunks of code that can be reused elsewhere as needed.  A deepy nested structure, like it seems you may have there, is the ideal use case for content projection using <ng-content>.  If its not possible to restructure the app like that, you can try importing and injecting ChangeDetectorRef into the component, and manually calling its detect changes method right after the line / assignment that is causing the error. It may help, but more than likely the error will just be a little farther down

Comment: read [Everything you need to know about the `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` error](https://blog.angularindepth.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-error-e3fd9ce7dbb4)

Comment: @diopside: yes, default ChangeDetectionStrategy
Thanks for the hint with the ng-template element.

Comment: @Vega: No, I use the tabs like in the examples of https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/tabs/examples with having form elements as tab content. But I haven't investigated yet how the code of the tab components looks like.

Comment: I forked already the ngb tab example and included form elements as tab content: http://embed.plnkr.co/lZgCb0cyX8TnZ2j8ZE4O/ But I still try to reproduce the error. Just having form elements in tabs seems not to lead to a ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError.
I didn't mention yet that I am loading form data in the ngOnInit Method by subscribing to observables, which makes the form valid. I get rid of the error if I put the form elements outside of the tabs or I do not load form data. (Then the form is always invalid.)  I will continue reproducing the error in the pluker code.

Comment: Finally, I could reproduce the error. See the plunker link in the previous comment. As soon as  the 'Last Name' Tab is clicked the ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError is thrown.

Comment: You can get rid of the ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError in the plunker demo by putting the form elements ahead of the tabs or by not loading form data asynchronously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your plunker, I see that you mixed  "template driven forms" and "reactive forms" patterns. You have `[(ngModel)]` and `formControlName` at the same time on the inputs. When you change the input value binded to the model formControl value is invalided, thus the error.

**[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/3vjfEW9Urve2i49K89pX?p=preview)**

Comment: See the added plunker

Comment: Would be interesting why the error occurs just in the two cases mentioned in the comments of the question.
However, thx!

Comment: When I used "reactive forms", I set "[attr.disabled]="hoo"" on input. So the error occur.

Comment: @Vega yeah. I stop mixing "template driven forms" and "reactive forms", the error doesn't occur.  Thanks giving me a hint.